# Booktabs, but with enclosing border around the table?

Tags: tables, formatting, rules

So I know that the `booktabs` package was designed without vertical lines in mind … but what if you still want a nice enclosing box around the table, `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` being a part of this?

I'm basically designing a truth table, and I want that nice `booktabs` look to it, with thicker `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` compared to `\midrules`, but with perhaps default thin vertical lines on the outer edges to create a feeling of enclosure. Not to mention a vertical line to seperate inputs from outputs.

**EDIT: Expected output follows …**

[image: Truth table]

Comment: The booktabs response would be that you don't need vertical lines on the outside of your table, because the margin of the page will create the enclosure, and that you can use table entries of "inputs" and "outputs" (along with a bit of white space) to create the visual separation between the two.

Comment: Well, in my particular case I'm making a very visual page with a lot of figures and boxes, and my truth tables are only taking up a tiny section of the page with paragraphs above and below and on the side. It would just make more sense to have an enclosing box around it as I'm enclosing other figures with boxes as well. I want the table to feel like an item that I can draw an arrow to later. Without the box it feels too "open" to have an arrow pointing to it, or even have it on the side of any text.

Answer (score 4):

You can nest two tabulars.

The name I gave to the environment should suggest what's my opinion about the output. `;-)`

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newenvironment{uglytabular}[2][c]
 {%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{|@{}c@{}|}
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{#2}
 }
 {%
  \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{uglytabular}{ccc}
\toprule
A & B & C \\
\midrule
x & y & z \\
u & v & w \\
\bottomrule
\end{uglytabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm contemplating the spaces above and below the vertical line that would separate the inputs from the outputs, whether it's bothering me, or whether it actually looks kind of cool.

Answer (score 4):

Since some people apparently can't imagine any circumstances where vertical lines would be (not-ugly and) useful - which they would in my particular case - and just call it out for being ugly, I'll try posting myself on a more serious note. As an engineer, I prefer the vertical lines, as they easily separate inputs from outputs, and they're also consistent with how I write the tables in my notes.

I ended up using egreg's solution, but finished it to match the question (with the vertical line in the middle) and without the need for degrading my personal preference (i.e. renaming `uglytabular` to a less cheeky name: `ttable`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newenvironment{ttable}[2][c]
 {%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{|@{}c@{}|}
  \rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!20}
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{#2}
 }
 {%
  \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}
 }

% Set hline to the default \midrule thickness:
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.05em}

\begin{document}

 \begin{ttable}{cc|c}
    \toprule
    A & B & X \\\hline
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{ttable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Truth table]

This is just the design I need in my particular case. Whether it be ugly in your case or not, it just fits perfectly with the specific style I'm going for, and that's a personal choice that should be respected.

Comment: Let's keep the tone serious in the answers, thank you. This answer is complete and ready for others to copy. Unless they want a i/o divider that's full length – I just happened to be satisfied with the length I got.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I tried to create a way to adjust the width or each line independently.  Most of the complexity for `\hline` is to make double lines using `\hline\hline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hwidth}[1]{%
  \noalign{\hrule \@height #1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|ccc|}
\hwidth{1pt}
A & B & C \\
\hwidth{.4pt}
x & y & z \\
u & v & w \\
\hwidth{1pt}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: That could be useful some day! :-D

Answer (score 1):

`booktabs` does not prohibit vertical lines, just that the general consensus is that they are not usually needed. However if you use vertical lines they are broken at the horizontal lines in the `tabular`.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|cc|c|}
\toprule 
A & B & C \\
\midrule
x & y & z \\
u & v & w \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

But from @JohnKormylo answer this can be fixed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hwidth}[1]{%
  \noalign{\hrule \@height #1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|cc|c|}
\hwidth{1pt}
%\toprule 
A & B & C \\
\hwidth{.4pt}
%\midrule
x & y & z \\
u & v & w \\
\hwidth{1pt}
%\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This might be a useful addtion to the `booktabs` package.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of `makecell` for the thicker lines, `cellspace` for some added space around the cells and `xcolor` with the `table` option to add alternating row colors:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{.65ex}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{.03em}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{tabular}{|cc|c|}
\Xhline{0.08em}
A & B & C \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\Xhline{0.08em}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```